# Why does HTTP/2 test say that I have ALPN support even if I only have OpenSSL1.0.1t?

Tags: apache-2.4, openssl, alpn

This question is kind of related to this [Why is ALPN not supported by my server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/831534/why-is-alpn-not-supported-by-my-server)

But in my case, the same [test](https://tools.keycdn.com/http2-test)  does say that ALPN is supported even if I am not using OpenSSL1.0.2 and only OpenSSL1.0.1t

I am currently using Apache2.4.25 with h2 activated. But it still bothers me that ALPN is supported even if my OpenSSL is supposed to not support it?

My http2.conf in conf-enabled:

```
Protocols h2 h2c http/1.1
H2Push          on  
H2PushPriority  *                       after  
H2PushPriority  text/css                before  
H2PushPriority  image/jpeg              after   32  
H2PushPriority  image/png               after   32  
H2PushPriority  application/javascript  interleaved
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3  
SSLHonorCipherOrder on  
SSLCipherSuite 'EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384       EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+RC4 EECDH EDH+aRSA !RC4 !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS'
```

Output from LDD:

```
╰─➤  ldd /usr/sbin/apache2                                                                                                                                                 1 ↵
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc4d593000)
libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007fa1c2492000)
libaprutil-1.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaprutil-1.so.0 (0x00007fa1c2269000)
libapr-1.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapr-1.so.0 (0x00007fa1c2034000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fa1c1e17000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa1c1a6c000)
libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007fa1c1867000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fa1c165f000)
libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007fa1c1428000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fa1c1224000)
libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007fa1c0ffb000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fa1c29a5000)
```

Counterquestions is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like apache 2.4.25 from the testing repo is compiled toghether with libssl 1.0.2, that explains why the server has ALPN support even if OpenSSL1.0.2 is not installed on the system.

Answer (score 2):

The `ldd` output doesn't include any reference to `libssl.so`. This indicates that your Apache uses a statically linked version of the SSL library which means that the OpenSSL is included in the Apache2 binary file.

So, your Apache2 does not use the SSL library on your system.

Comment: So, does that mean that apache has ALPN support? Does "Protocols h2 h2c http/1.1" have anything to do with it?

Comment: Your Apache has ALPN support if it has been statically linked with OpenSSL 1.0.2 version. You might be able to find details on your Apache by looking at the information provided by the packager.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot find any other explanation than suggesting you might have two versions of openSSL installed (or the test results are wrong).

Apache2's mod_http2 is based on nghttp2, and its docs (https://nghttp2.org/documentation/nghttpx-howto.html#alpn-support) state:

> **ALPN support**
>
> ALPN support requires OpenSSL >= 1.0.2.

Curiously, the release notes for 1.0.1t (https://www.openssl.org/news/openssl-1.0.1-notes.html) mention:

> Modify behavior of ALPN to invoke callback after SNI/servername callback, such that updates to the SSL_CTX affect ALPN.

Tracking down that message leads to https://github.com/openssl/openssl/commit/1316ca80f4e1dc9339572c780d495f995fe0bad0.

That however seems to only have contributed code to 1.1.0 - I could not find evidence of its changes in 1.0.1t.

In theory, ALPN and NPN are *very* closely related (https://hpbn.co/transport-layer-security-tls/#application-layer-protocol-negotiation-alpn) - the main difference between the two being who announces the protocols.
But I simply cannot find a logical explanation to your findings, so have to ask if you are certain of your premises.

You can serve HTTP/2 without ALPN (I checked using the test/tool you linked to), but I cannot find anything to explain why ALPN would be shown as supported.

The only other lead I could find is a bug report for RH, where this issue is discussed at some length:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1276310

There are suggestions that the RH team may do something about it, but I don't see any clear indication of a backport of ALPN into 1.0.1.
And don't know whether a RedHat related discussion is relevant in your case.

Comment: Could this in conf-enabled/http2.conf be the answer?
"Protocols h2 h2c http/1.1"

Comment: There is only one version of OpenSSL installed. so the only exaplanation is that the test is wrong. But it has been wrong for month and should'nt a quite big company have verified that their test works correctly?

Comment: I unfortunately don't have anything I can use to test, so it is a bit hard to answer. It might be worth using curl (e.g. `curl --http2`) or a browser (see https://icing.github.io/mod_h2/howto.html) to confirm what the check returns. If these agree that ALPN is available, then I think it might be necessary to look a bit further into your apache build, and how it was compiled.

Comment: Have you checked with `ldd` which libraries Apache uses?

Comment: @iwaseatenbyagrue I can confirm that HTTP/2 is running from a webbrowser and via the apache access.log. So HTTP/2 is runnig fine.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen I have added that information to the original question

Comment: @Orphans - HTTP/2 unfortunately doesn't prove it, because I can support HTTP/2 without ALPN (properly being another matter) - when you check via your browser, do you see _any_ mention of ALPN one way or another?

Comment: @iwaseatenbyagrue yes, I am aware of that. Using chrome://net-internals/#http2 to check the ID of the site that is supposed to have ALPN enabled - but I can not find any mention of it there. Where am I supposed to find it in the browser?

Comment: @iwaseatenbyagrue also, according to https://http2.pro/, I have ALPN.
I do not understand why I have it when I am supposed to not have support for it.

Comment: @iwaseatenbyagrue Interesting note on https://http2.pro:
This server supports Application-Level Protocol Negotiation. ALPN is a TLS extension that helps client and server negotiate the HTTP protocol (h2 in this case) during the TLS handshake. This avoids the need to make a regular HTTP/1.1 request in order to establish an h2 connection.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on the ALPN question directly, but `ldd` shouldn't be used on `/usr/sbin/apache2` unless `apachectl -M` indicates that ssl_module or http2_module are static instead of shared (shared being the default for most modules). use `ldd $(locate mod_ssl.so)` resp. `ldd $(locate mod_http2.so)` instead. From there it should be possible to find out against which version you are really linked.